# Datatable Compare Rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable object, which is populated from a webservice.

Apparently, the web service just throws everything (data) back to me.  The data which gets in my datatable looks like this:

```
Dept      Code    Value
Science   ABC     5
Science   ABC     6
Science   DEF     7
Math      ABC     3
Math      DEF     9
English   ABC     2
English   DEF     3
English   DEF     4
English   DEF     5
```

Now, I want to create a datatable that will calculate (and sum)/ eliminate the values in the datatable, so that the new datatable would have the data like:

```
Dept      Code    Value
Science   ABC     11
Science   DEF     7
Math      ABC     3
Math      DEF     9
English   ABC     2
English   DEF     12
```

Please take note that I could only modify the datatable.

Can anyone help me? VB.Net please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple summary query will give you what you want:

```
SELECT Dept, Code, SUM(Value) sum_value FROM datatable GROUP BY Dept, Code
```

You could also create a view with that `SQL definition`, so you could
just query the view as you would a table.  If you start to get so much 
data that the query is slow, you'll want to store the results in a 
permanent table - but for moderate amounts of data this should work fine.

Comment: I cannot modify the SQL for this matter. As I have mentioned, I am getting a datatable object whose data is thrown in by a webservice.  That is why I need to make the modifications on the datatable.

Comment: Ahh, the actual DataTable object ... I'll poke around some more. :-)

Comment: This has provided me an insight to create another datatable populated by iterating through the original datatable and summing up the values before inserting to the new datatable object.